# How do I remember my password with Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I clicked "don't remember passwords for this website" and now I want to cancel this selection and remember my password when I login. How do I do it? I'm using Internet Explorer 11.

Answer (score 0):

Its available on the official site

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/internet-explorer/fill-in-forms-remember-passwords-autocomplete#ie=ie-11

If its OFF, Turn it ON & try to access the site once more. It should work the next time you access this site.

Comment: "Tap or click Options, and under Passwords, turn Offer to save passwords when I log into sites to On." - there are no options in settings.

Comment: I'm guessing from the instruction to swipe its for Windows 8. Can you try this instead ? http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-disable-the-save-password-prompt-in-internet-explorer-11-2/. Sorry I can't verify I don't have IE11 on any of my setups

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I deleted all my browsing history and it worked. I didn't find a way to remove a specific website from the list of websites of which Internet Explorer will not remember passwords.